# Can Titanium Backup successfully backup and restore Google Authenticator between ROMs?

Tags: backup, 4.4-kitkat, titanium-backup, nexus-5, google-authenticator

I have a rooted Nexus 5 running stock 4.4.2. I want to install another ROM such as PA4 or CM11 (also 4.4.x based), but I have about 5-odd items in my Google Authenticator install which are a pain to configure all over again on the 'new' device. Will using Titanium Backup to backup and restore Google Authenticator preserve the settings and tokens?

I read somewhere that it doesn't work if you move between major versions of the OS and even though I'm moving from 4.4 to 4.4, I am changing the base ROM, so I'm not so sure.

If anyone has tried this and hasn't been able to move GA over gracefully, I might just stick around with the stock ROM for a little while longer, because I only just got this phone a couple weeks ago.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but: You might consider taking a Nandroid backup before you flash the new ROM (which you should do anyway). So in case it does *not* work out, you at least can revert easily to the previous ROM by restoring the Nandroid backup, and "continue where you left".

Comment: Nandroid... Now that's a name I've not heard in a long, long time!

Comment: It's even mentioned in our fine [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). Also has [its own fine tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info). Just in case :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It worked fine for me.

I recently replaced my Sony Xperia Z with a Nexus 5. I copied over the Titanium Backup files and restored them, including Google Authenticator. No problems to report, I can still connect correctly to sites and apps requiring a code.

Comment: This is very promising!